# Dexie return values from second query

Tags: typescript, indexeddb, dexie

I have Typescript code where I put some data into IndexedDB using Dexie, and next I try to pull it out using where or other method. Everytime first call for get data from DB return undefined value or empty array (depends on query), and second execute (same query) return good data.

For inserting data I use put method on Table object (https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.put())

`await Table.put(someObject)`

For getting data I tried different way

https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.where()

`await Table.where('index_name').equals('value').firts();`

`await Table.where('index_name').equals('value').toArray();`

`await Table.toArray();`

So more real code looks like that:

```
await database.tableName.put(myObject);
... some code ...
await database.tableName.where('name').equals(myObject.name); // return undefined
await database.tableName.where('name').equals(myObject.name); // return myObject
```

other way:

```
await database.tableName.put(myObject);
... some code ...
await database.tableName.toArray(); // return empty array
await database.tableName.toArray(); // return array with myObject
```

Each of method as first time always return undefined/empty array, always from the second execute (line by line) return correct value (correct object instance). Between saving and load data there is few instructions (also other save in the same table).

Comment: I think you would need to explain this a bit more in detail. It is hard to understand the issue.

Comment: @DavidFahlander I added more detailed explanation

Comment: I have the same =((